# Preserving incidence relation proof

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

How can one prove via analytic method that projective map preserves incidence relation?

Answer (score 2):

A point $p$ is incident with a set $S$ iff $p\in S$. Given how we define the image of $S$ under a map, how could a map fail to preserve incidence?